# How to extract dynamic value from Jmeter request body?

Tags: encryption, postman, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

i want to extract some token named, "encryptedstr" from jmeter request body. That token is not available in the response of any other previous requests.
The sampler is just after login.
How can i extract from request body? or is it related to login encryption?

Comment: you mean it's JSON parameter? can you give example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to **extract** the variable from the request as it makes no any sense.

I believe you need to **generate** this parameter somehow, looking into its name I would assume that it contains encrypted request data parameters so it might be the case you need to use [__digest() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) or if the encryption logic is more complex - use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for calculating the parameter value.

With regards to encryption algorithm - contact your application developers or use [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to inspect the corresponding JavaScript function.